# How to Plot Signal Flow Graph

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm currently doing some problem related to digital signal analysis and processing on matlab. I have given a transfer function of 4th order discrete time as shown below.
[image]

I have find out the pole & zeros and then convert it to second order section model as

```
>> b = [0.0018 0.0073 0.011 0.007 0.008];
>> a = [1 -3.0544 3.8291 -2.2925 0.55072];
>> [z,p,k]=tf2zp(b,a);
>> [sos,temp]=zp2sos(z,p,k);
```

Now I have to draw signal flow graph of value store on [sos](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/zp2sos.html) to represent cascaded structure. My Question is :- Is there any function available or not to draw signal flow graph in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of tools on Matlab's FileExchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33735-symbolic-reduction-of-block-diagrams-and-signal-flow-graphs

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7224-a-fully-automated-flowgraph-analysis-tool-for-matlab

I don't think there is an original Matlab tool.

Comment: @nKandel Please explain what is a signal flow diagram then.

Comment: @EitanT almost they are alike but in block diagram we represent diagram with delay blocks not with nodes.